# google cloud IAM workload identity federation with azure ad 'app registration'/'enterprise applications'

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-iam, google-identity, workload-identity

I'm trying to setup Azure AD 'Enterprise Application' to access google cloud from myapps.microsoft.com for both identity and access.

I set up workload identity federation as described in https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/configuring-workload-identity-federation#azure, however authentication is not working fine with below error.

```
gcloud auth login --cred-file="/Users/pavan-mac/Downloads/clientLibraryConfig-aad-oidc.json"       

ERROR: gcloud crashed (TransportError): HTTPConnectionPool(host='169.254.169.254', port=80): Max retries exceeded with url: /metadata/identity/oauth2/token?api-version=2018-02-01&resource=https%3A%2F%2Fiam.googleapis.com%2Fprojects%<removed>%2Flocations%2Fglobal%2FworkloadIdentityPools%2Faad-integration%2Fproviders%2Faad-oidc (Caused by NewConnectionError('<urllib3.connection.HTTPConnection object at 0x7feb69c80a10>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 60] Operation timed out'))
```

My commands:

```
➜ ~ gcloud iam workload-identity-pools create "azure-ad-integration" \ --location="global" \ --description="azure-ad-integration" \ --display-name="azure-ad-integration" 
Created workload identity pool [azure-ad-integration]. 
➜ ~ gcloud iam workload-identity-pools providers create-oidc azure-ad-oidc-provider\ --location="global" \ --workload-identity-pool="azure-ad-integration"\ --issuer-uri="sts.windows.net/<removed-tenant-id>" \ --allowed-audiences="api://<removed-app-id-uri>" \ --attribute-mapping="google.subject=assertion.sub,google.groups=assertion.groups" 
Created workload identity pool provider [azure-ad-oidc-provider].
➜ ~ gcloud iam service-accounts add-iam-policy-binding <removed-svc-account> \ --role roles/iam.workloadIdentityUser \ --member "principalSet://iam.googleapis.com/projects/<removed-project-number>/locations/global/workloadIdentityPools/azure-ad-integration/*" 
Updated IAM policy for serviceAccount [<service-acocunt>@<project>.iam.gserviceaccount.com]. bindings: 
 - members: 
  - principalSet://iam.googleapis.com/projects/<removed-project-number>/locations/global/workloadIdentityPools/azure-ad-integration/* role: roles/iam.workloadIdentityUser etag: BwXTqFEUIVo=
➜ ~ gcloud iam workload-identity-pools create-cred-config projects/<removed-project-num>/locations/global/workloadIdentityPools/azure-ad-integration/providers/azure-ad-oidc-provider\ --service-account='<service-account>@<project>.gserviceaccount.com'\ --azure \ --app-id-uri 'api://<app-id-uri>'\ --output-file=FILEPATH.json
 Created credential configuration file [FILEPATH.json].
➜  ~ gcloud version
Google Cloud SDK 367.0.0
bq 2.0.72
core 2021.12.10
gsutil 5.5
➜  ~
```

2 questions:

1. I suspect the issue is around attribute mapping.  What's the ideal config to specify attributes when using Azure AD OIDC provider?
2. I would like to be able to assign users/groups in Azure AD enterprise application with mapped roles in google cloud (say, owner/editor/viewer roles) using workload federation feature in GCP.  Can someone help me understand how to link the roles from azure ad to service account in GCP with correct attributes mapping?

Comment: Edit your question and show the details of how you set up Workload Identity Federation.

Comment: One item I noticed after formatting the error message. The CLI is accessing the metadata server path **/metadata/identity/oauth2/token**. That probably means you have disabled either the service account at the instance or disabled all OAuth scopes. That disables the Metadata server which means you cannot then generate tokens from metadata. That would explain why **gcloud** failed (but it really should not crash.

Comment: Thanks @JohnHanley for quick response! ➜  ~ gcloud iam workload-identity-pools create "azure-ad-integration" \
  --location="global" \
  --description="azure-ad-integration" \
  --display-name="azure-ad-integration"
Created workload identity pool [azure-ad-integration].

Comment: I am not using any VM instance in this case to associate/set access for service account.  I am hoping Azure AD Enterprise Application with role definitions help trigger the impersonation.  Please let me know the correct approach if this doesn't work.  I hope to be able to integrate SSO + Access (role impersonation) from myapps.microsoft.com

Comment: Please delete all those comments and add them to your question. Which version of the CLI?

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using the CLI outside of an Azure Virtual Machine you do not have access to an Azure Managed Identity. That is the reason for the error regarding the metadata server **169.254.169.254//metadata/identity/oauth2/token**

One of the requirements/options for Workload Identity Federation is to create or assign a managed identity to the resource you are running the Google Cloud CLI on.

[Preparing the external identity provider](https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/configuring-workload-identity-federation#prepare)

> To let an application obtain access tokens for the Azure AD
> application, you can use managed identities

In this Google document a trick is demonstrated that requires you to fetch an Access Token yourself from the Azure instance metadata service and paste that into the assertion. I have not tried that technique but would mean everytime the token expires you would need to repeat the process.

```
curl \
  "http://169.254.169.254/metadata/identity/oauth2/token?resource=APP_ID_URI&api-version=2018-02-01" \
  -H "Metadata: true" | jq -r .access_token
```

[Obtain an access token from the Azure Instance Metadata Service (IMDS)](https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/configuring-workload-identity-federation#mapping_service_identities)

Comment: Hi John, I assigned managed identity to a VM and ran it, but no luck. The doc says, create app registration and managed identity but I don't find a way to grant access for managed identity on app registration/enterprise applications.  I was hoping to see the step by step guide similar to  https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hANDWau9NvE to access google cloud using AAD OIDC provider and it isn't clear.  I want enterprise application (instance of app registration in Azure AD) to do identity and access (based on role assigned) to get access to gcp project.  Any help greatly appreciated.